# How can I center 3 divs (canvas with SVG axis) using bootstrap

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css, svg, canvas

I have 3 divs

1. One is the canvas (fully responsive and resized automatically on window resize)
2. is a vertical axis made with SVG
3. is an horizontal axis made with SVG

Here how my code looks like

```js
    var size = 300;
   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('g-canvas', {
      selection: false,
        backgroundColor: "#91653a",
      });
    canvas.setHeight(size);
    canvas.setWidth(size);
    $('#left-svg').attr({height:size});
    $('#bottom-svg').attr({width:size + 57});
    $('#svg-left-line').attr({y2:size});
    $('#svg-bottom-line').attr({x2:size + 10});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.toolMenu {
  text-align: center;
}

#gSelect {
  margin: 10px;
}

line{
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

#left-canvas {
  display: flex;
  margin:10px;
}

#bottom-canvas {
  height: 10px;
}

#bottom-canvas svg {
  height: 10px;
}

#left-svg {
  width: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}

#bottom-svg{
  padding-left: 57px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="col col-md-6 g-container-upper">
 <div id="g-container" >
  <div id="left-canvas" class="row justify-content-md-center">
   <svg id="left-svg">
    <g>
     <line id="svg-left-line" x1="5" x2="5" y1="0"></line>
    </g>
    <g></g>
   </svg>
   <canvas id="g-canvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
  <div id="bottom-canvas">
   <svg id="bottom-svg" class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <g>
     <line id="svg-bottom-line" x1="0" y1="5" y2="5"></line>
    </g>
   </svg>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

In this piece of code I've tried put the general idea of the thing but in reality I'm using angular and I'm refreshing a lot of dom elements live in order to make everything have the good size. Now my problem is I don't know how to manipulate this as a whole object to center it for example and keepin everything stucked together.

As I don't always understand all css's subtilities I also get parent div not the same the same width as children without having a chance to see in the DOM inspector where that particular size comes from.

Any help is greatly appreciated ;)

Comment: do you want .g-container-upper div in the center of screen?

Comment: hum from what I see it's more  `g-container-upper`

Comment: i answered hope it is useful.

Comment: I cannot test it right now but I will mark as answered if it worked. Many thanks

Comment: do you want only horizontally center? or you want vertically center also?

Comment: just verticallty thank you

Comment: but as per your code you need to provide a height to .row for vertically center.

Comment: sorry just horizontlly I meant

Comment: without height only horizontally center is possible.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
    var size = 300;
   var canvas = new fabric.Canvas('g-canvas', {
      selection: false,
        backgroundColor: "#91653a",
      });
    canvas.setHeight(size);
    canvas.setWidth(size);
    $('#left-svg').attr({height:size});
    $('#bottom-svg').attr({width:size + 57});
    $('#svg-left-line').attr({y2:size});
    $('#svg-bottom-line').attr({x2:size + 10});
```

```css
ul,
li {
  display: inline;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 2px;
}

ul {
  text-align: center;
  padding-left: 0px;
}

.toolMenu {
  text-align: center;
}

#gSelect {
  margin: 10px;
}

line{
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  stroke-miterlimit: 10;
}

#left-canvas {
  display: flex;
  margin:10px;
}

#bottom-canvas {
  height: 10px;
}

#bottom-canvas svg {
  height: 10px;
}

#left-svg {
  width: 10px;
  margin-right: 5px;
}
.g-container-upper {
    margin: 0px auto;
}
#bottom-svg{
  padding-left: 57px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/fabric.js/2.4.6/fabric.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.6/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-wHAiFfRlMFy6i5SRaxvfOCifBUQy1xHdJ/yoi7FRNXMRBu5WHdZYu1hA6ZOblgut" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-B0UglyR+jN6CkvvICOB2joaf5I4l3gm9GU6Hc1og6Ls7i6U/mkkaduKaBhlAXv9k" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
<div class="row">
<div class="g-container-upper">
 <div id="g-container" >
  <div id="left-canvas" class="row justify-content-md-center">
   <svg id="left-svg">
    <g>
     <line id="svg-left-line" x1="5" x2="5" y1="0"></line>
    </g>
    <g></g>
   </svg>
   <canvas id="g-canvas" style="border:1px solid #000000;"></canvas>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
  <div id="bottom-canvas">
   <svg id="bottom-svg" class="row justify-content-md-center">
    <g>
     <line id="svg-bottom-line" x1="0" y1="5" y2="5"></line>
    </g>
   </svg>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```